# Can I use https for the regular canvas URL?

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-canvas

Can I use the same URL for both 'Canvas URL' and 'Secure Canvas URL' - where both are HTTPS?

The browser does not seem to issue warnings regarding https components in an http page, but is it OK as far as Facebook policy is concerned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same https url for both. But unfortunately this only works for `Canvas URL` and `Secure Canvas URL` but not for `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL`.

Seems like a bug to me, since you can set a https url there too, but the protocol is ignored in the request to your site.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. +1 for the Page Tab URL issue. I also found it here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18808, so the solution to this is redirecting.

Comment: That bug report has been closed since they decided to move away from Bugzilla. New bug report is here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220661014669375

Answer (score 0):

Facebook policy is for all apps to be served via HTTPS.

Comment: Does that mean the answer to my question is yes? I can use https for the regular canvas URL as well?

Comment: I dont think it will matter what is entered into the http box as FaceBook will use the https url as per policy.